# What is "persönliche Zinswende"?

Tags: english-to-german

I came across the following sentence in [Spiegel](http://www.spiegel.de/wirtschaft/service/girokonto-und-tagesgeld-bankkunden-entgehen-viele-zinsen-a-1071071.html):

> Soll es mehr sichere Rendite sein, hilft den Kunden in vielen Fällen eben doch nur **die persönliche Zinswende**.

Context: Big German banks pay their customers on fix-term deposits generally no more than 0.01% interest per year. So, the only way out for customers in search of better yields is "persönliche Zinswende".

Comment: This is not an official term. Maybe you should read the Spiegel-article to understand what the author wants to tell us.

Comment: My analysis from the article: Some banks will not pay more interests. So you have to increase your interests by changing the bank.

Comment: Hubert, I actually have read the article. This sentence just pops up at the very end. Is this a bad question? Should I delete it?

Comment: @EugeneStr. No, it’s an okay question. No, you shouldn’t delete it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Zinswende* is the situation where the interest rate starts to rise again after a long fall (or starts to sink after a long rise). This expression is common and generally understood, at least in economic contexts.

Since the *Zinswende* at large doesn’t seem to be happening, the article gives recommendations how someone at least can get slightly higher interest on their savings. If they follow the advice, they accomplish their *persönliche Zinswende*.